# Career 2.0 can't import project hosted in eclipse labs that is part of google code

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, jobs

[Eclipse labs](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/hosting/) is a project hosting based on Google code, Careear 2.0 can't recognize its profile as a profile of Google code. However Career 2.0 think the main page of project as Google code project if importing it as other open source hosting.

Comment: Indeed, this seems like an issue.

Comment: @olovb any updates on the resolution of the problem?

Comment: No, I still cannot get my Eclipse labs project accepted as a *google code* one or *other* one ...

Answer (score 2):

I have update the google code import to support loading projects from eclipse labs as well.  This should be live in the next hour or so.